# Axios does not return XML error message from S3 when uploading asset over the size limit

Tags: node.js, xml, amazon-s3, axios

Axios does not return XML error message from S3 when uploading asset over the size limit.

Environment

- Axios Version : 0.24.0
- Node.js Version: v14.17.4
- OS: Mac OS 12.3

S3 is returning this XML error message when I try to uplaod an asset over teh size limit

```
UPLOAD FAILED. Status Code: 400. Error message: 
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>EntityTooLarge</Code><Message>Your proposed upload exceeds the maximum allowed size</Message><ProposedSize>52432788</ProposedSize><MaxSizeAllowed>52428800</MaxSizeAllowed><RequestId>N8RFYCS0K10GB4FF</RequestId><HostId>2OaG69rf19DMxItXx8J//rscZuSbxU8hJ/93du/a1zaFwAZa6jN2v1xCDebW4MRMgW3Kfuw0n10=</HostId></Error>
```

But Axios:

- does not return it, just returns a generic error message: `Request failed with status code 400"`
- and also breaks when trying to parse it.

This is the code I am running for the upload to S3:

```
let dataForm = new FormData();

dataForm.append('key', functionParams.uploadData.fields.key);
dataForm.append('bucket', functionParams.uploadData.fields.bucket);
dataForm.append('X-Amz-Algorithm', functionParams.uploadData.fields['X-Amz-Algorithm']);
dataForm.append('X-Amz-Credential', functionParams.uploadData.fields['X-Amz-Credential']);
dataForm.append('X-Amz-Date', functionParams.uploadData.fields['X-Amz-Date']);
dataForm.append('Policy', functionParams.uploadData.fields.Policy);
dataForm.append('X-Amz-Signature', functionParams.uploadData.fields['X-Amz-Signature']);
dataForm.append('file', fs.createReadStream(functionParams.assetFullPath),
            { knownLength: fs.statSync(functionParams.assetFullPath).size }  
        );

const uploadServiceURL = uploadData.url;

var config = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: uploadServiceURL,
            headers: {
                ...dataForm.getHeaders(),
                'content-length': dataForm.getLengthSync()
            },
            data: dataForm,
            maxContentLength: Infinity,
            maxBodyLength: Infinity,
            transitional: {
                forcedJSONParsing: false,
                silentJSONParsing: false,
                clarifyTimeoutError: true
            }
        };


        axios(config)
            .then(answer => {
                  resolve(answer);
            })
            .catch((error) => {               
                console.log(`Error:`)               
                console.log(error.toJSON())
                reject(error)
            })
```

This is the error I get from Axios:

```
{
   "message": "Request failed with status code 400",
   "name": "Error",
   "stack": "Error: Request failed with status code 400\n    at createError (/Users/vlad/modules/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)\n    at settle (/Users/vlad/modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)\n    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/Users/vlad/modules/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:322:11)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:412:35)\n    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)",
   "config": {
      "transitional": {
         "silentJSONParsing": false,
         "forcedJSONParsing": false,
         "clarifyTimeoutError": true
      },
      "transformRequest": [
         null
      ],
      "transformResponse": [
         null
      ],
      "timeout": 0,
      "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
      "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
      "maxContentLength": null,
      "maxBodyLength": null,
      "headers": {
         "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
         "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------913873697821807580301477",
         "content-length": 114310407,
         "User-Agent": "axios/0.26.0"
      },
      "method": "post",
      "url": "https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/public-assets.bluescape.com",
      "data": {
         "_overheadLength": 938,
         "_valueLength": 114309413,
         "_valuesToMeasure": [],
         "writable": false,
         "readable": true,
         "dataSize": 0,
         "maxDataSize": 2097152,
         "pauseStreams": true,
         "_released": true,
         "_streams": [],
         "_currentStream": null,
         "_insideLoop": false,
         "_pendingNext": false,
         "_boundary": "--------------------------913873697821807580301477",
         "_events": {},
         "_eventsCount": 1
      },
      "axios-retry": {
         "retryCount": 0,
         "lastRequestTime": 1648080399442
      }
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

Any idea how can I get back the XML from S3 describing the issue?
I want to present it as the cause of the error.

I have tried using “transformResponse“ to transform the response from remote server, but I cannot make it work and accept a new error message:

```
var config = {
           method: 'POST',
           url: uploadServiceURL,
           headers: {
               ...dataForm.getHeaders(),
               'content-length': dataForm.getLengthSync()
           },
           data: dataForm,
           maxContentLength: Infinity,
           maxBodyLength: Infinity,
           transformResponse: [(response, headers) => {
 
               var resp = response;
               // Note: A successful upload to S3 will return an empty response, status code 204
               if (response) {
                   console.log(` ---> response for ${functionParams.assetFullPath} : ${JSON.stringify(response, null, '   ')} `)
 
                   var resp;
 
                   try {
                       // Detect an error when parsing the answer: XML or something else
                       resp = JSON.parse(response)
                       console.log(`==> answer parsed:`)
                       console.log(JSON.stringify(resp, null, '   '))
                   } catch (error) {
                       console.log(` ===> ERROR parsing response for ${functionParams.assetFullPath}: ${JSON.stringify(error, null, '   ')}`)
 
 
                       // Trying to construct an XML response
                       resp = {
                           "test message": "manually created error message"
 
                       }
 
                   }
               }
               console.log(`----> Response to send back: ${JSON.stringify(resp, null, '   ')}`)
 
               return resp;
 
 
           }, ...axios.defaults.transformRequest],
           transitional: {
               forcedJSONParsing: false,
               silentJSONParsing: false,
               clarifyTimeoutError: true
           }
       };
```

Answer (score 0):

Axios cannot automatically parse XML. You can get the response as a string if you use the `text` response type.

```js
config = {...config, responseType: 'text'}
```

Then, the response will be included in `answer.data` as a string. Of course, if you need to do anything smarter than just printing the response, you'll still need to parse it by using the [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), for example.

Comment: Did the change, it does not work. The XML is not part of `response.data` and it still triggers the internal parsing error that breaks the delivery of the error at all.